# Angular - How to create 2d array in angular dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array, undefined, push

I Have been trying to figure out how can I make this array dynamically and send it to my `api`. The structure of array is given below.

```
Photos[image][0] = "a.png"
Photos[image][1] = "b.png"
Photos[image][2] = "c.png"
```

How can I do this in controller I am stuck every time I apply some solution I get this error `Cannot set property '0' of undefined angular array`. I think I still dont know what kind of array is this. so far I have implement this solution but God knows why is this headache.

I have three files in this object

```
 $scope.files = [file,file,file].
```

and i need to put them in the array in the required format I mentioned above. This is my code.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.file.length; i++) {
        Photos[image] = {};
        Photos[image][i]=  $scope.file[i];
    }
    console.log(Photos);
```

Please elaborate my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out the documentation for angular foreach.

[Angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

This will allow you to iterate over each file in $scope.files. Each file can then be added to your Photos array as you see fit.